# cannot insert into android sqlite database when creating database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I created a SQLite database and I want to insert some initial data into it. so I put the insert "into query" in the "onCreate" method.
but it does not insert any values into database and it is empty after create!

here is my code:

```
package com.example.db;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String TABLE_GAME_LIST = "steps";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_STATUS = "status";
  public static final String COLUMN_HELP_COUNT = "helpCount";
  public static final String COLUMN_EAREASED = "earased";
  public static final String COLUMN_SPEED = "speed";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "earaser.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_GAME_LIST + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer, " 
      + COLUMN_STATUS
      +" integer, "
      + COLUMN_HELP_COUNT
      +" integer, "
      + COLUMN_EAREASED
      +" string, "
      + COLUMN_SPEED
      +" integer"
      + " );";


  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
      database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);


      database.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_GAME_LIST+"("+COLUMN_ID + ","
                + COLUMN_STATUS + ","
                        + COLUMN_HELP_COUNT + ","
                                + COLUMN_EAREASED + ","
                                        + COLUMN_SPEED + ") VALUES(14, 1, 2, "+"third"+", 5)");
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GAME_LIST);
        onCreate(db);
  }

}
```

Comment: try this  `database.execSQL("INSERT INTO steps(_id,status,helpCount,earased,speed) VALUES (14, 1, 2, 'third', 5));"`

Comment: you mean :   `database.execSQL("INSERT INTO steps(_id,status,helpCount,earased,speed) VALUES (14, 1, 2, +"+"third"+", 5)");`    I tested it but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in the SQL, such as string values that need to be `'quoted'`, such as `third`.

Since you didn't get an exception, the SQL wasn't run. Uninstall your app so that the old version of the database gets removed and `onCreate()` is run again. [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Comment: YEEEEEEEES! such a hidden problem! queries in onCreate method run just at install time. so after uninstalling the app and install again, it works. thanks dear laalto ;)